# How to call Adsense code within another JS file?

Tags: javascript, adsense

I work for an AD serving platform with used a CDN service to serve ads. We can only upload static files to the CDN. If we want to serve Adsense or other Advertising JS snippets eg. like this below:

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- site 180x150 -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:180px;height:150px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxx"
     data-ad-slot="xxxx"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Creating a JS file and uploading it to the CDN doesn't work. The code doesn't get called. I have tried rewriting the code as document.write() but it doesn't work either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

write was the right solution actually, carriage return was the issue. here the code:

```
document.write('<script async  src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script><!--     responsive pbsqrd --><ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:block" data-ad-    client="ca-pub-xxxx" data-ad-slot="xxxx" data-ad-format="auto"></ins><script>    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});</script>');
```